# GeoIP ImportError: No module named django.core.management

Tags: django, importerror, geoip, pythonpath, traceback

I have website running successfully all models, views, admin all functional. Now isntalled GeoIP by manual added to the settings.py.

I ran the command

```
python2.7 manage.py syncdb

Creating tables ...
Creating table django_geoip_country
Creating table django_geoip_region
Creating table django_geoip_city
Creating table django_geoip_iprange
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

Ran the 2nd command

```
python manage.py geoip_update

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Not sure what is wrong here are the docs:

http://django-geoip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: Do you have django installed? Why do you use `python2.7` in the first command but not the second?

Comment: This site is running django like 2 years no problem, python2.7 I am running cause its on webfaction server all commands are like that. What I only did was I added 'django_geoip' to installed apps and synced the db. Then I wanted to update it but that error came up...

Comment: Do you need `python2.7` in the second command as well? i.e. `python2.7 manage.py geoip_update`?

Comment: Yes, because based on the docs it will update the db: Obtain latest data to perform geoip detection by running management command:    python2.7 manage.py geoip_update

Comment: I see that, I'm just saying in your code you left out the `2.7` part in the second command.

Comment: oh woow I am so sorry, I was blind or something thanks a lot, it works :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51922/discussion-between-rentgeeen-and-alex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you used python2.7 to run syncdb by python to run geoip_update, does the issue resolve itself running the following?

```
python2.7 manage.py geoip_update
```

You can check that python and python2.7 are in fact the same command by running which:

```
which python
which python2.7
```

I would recommend using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) to maintain project dependencies and avoid python versioning issues.